# Parse.com create or update many users

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm currently running into an issue creating or updating a large amount of users (200+) at once.  Here's the issues of found so far:

1. **Existing solution** - Keeping users as Users, I must fetch all users with my list of email addresses, `saveAll()` changes to users with the existing email addresses and then `signUp()` users who do not exist.  The problem here is running into the request limit.
2. **Problematic solution** - I believe I could use a `saveAll()` method if the users were not Users, but then I lose the ability to store passwords and use the `signIn()` method associated with it
3. **Problematic solution** - User a background job: I haven't tried this but, "Jobs that are initiated after the maximum concurrent limit has been reached will be terminated immediately" scares me a bit as well.

The reason I need this is because I need a company to be able to upload their users for use in our application.  The users have information stored about them and can log in to check the information, so I would really like being able to use the User class.

Another option would be to pay to up the request limit, but if we jump to creating/updating 2000+ users, we'll be right back to the same scenario...

Comment: to me which absolutely don't know what parse.com is, it's not very clear what you want to do and what are the problems you're facing. Also, can you tell us more about the used technical environment ?

Comment: @pomeh Sorry, I could post my existing implementation (rather lengthy), but without knowledge of how Parse works, I think it would be difficult to really help out here.  Parse has a javascript SDK that I am using to communicate with their BaaS.  I do think that if anyone else has had an issue similar to mine they would understand the question with the details I've presented already.

Comment: @Uxonith - have you thought of using a cloud code function?  I have not done it personally, but i know that it is possible to modify other User objects with the master key using the cloud code environment

Comment: @user2163298 I think I am going to implement a "job" for this and see how that works.  My understanding was that the Cloud Code still used up the Request Limit, but I could be wrong.